# Update Pivot Table Row Label with a Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter/update Pivot Table Row Label with a cell "A1" value automatically.
I tried to stitch random codes I found:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim A1Value As String

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then

Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Test")
A1Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

pt.ManualUpdate = True 

With Field
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueEquals, Value1:="A1Value"
End With

pt.RefreshTable
pt.ManualUpdate = False

End If
End Sub
```

I get an error

> "Invalid procedure"

at `.PivotFilters.Add...`.

I tried adding quotes on "A1Value" but I get the same error.

I also tried `.PivotItems("A1Value").Visible`.

I'm trying to filter the "Test" Field with a value in Cell "A1".

I have the code in Sheet 1, and the Pivot table is in Sheet 2.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the error message, and note the line that throws it, thanks!

Comment: [PivotFilters.Add Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfilters.add)
Value1  Optional Variant Filter value 1.

Comment: I've already been to that page, but thanks for the link.
I changed it to Value1 but I get an different error "Invalid Procedure Call"

Answer (score 1):

I changed this line of code

```
.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueEquals, Value1:="A1Value"
```

To

```
.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=A1Value
```

Also don't need a quotation around A1Value